# Search key value in NSDictionary array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search, nsdictionary

Hello I have an `Array` it has NSDictionaries.

```
1st object->["111":title of the video]
2nd object->["123":title of the other]
3rd object->["133":title of  another]
```

Let's say I want to search `123` Key in this `Array` and get the value of it. How can I do it?
Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
var subCatTitles=[AnyObject]()
let dict=[catData![0]:catData![4]]
self.subCatTitles.append(dict)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Array of Dictionaries for Value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203443/search-array-of-dictionaries-for-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you have an array like this:

```
var anArray: [NSDictionary] = [
    ["111": "title of the video"],
    ["123": "title of the other"],
    ["133": "title of another"]
]
```

This will work:

```
if let result = anArray.flatMap({$0["123"]}).first {
    print(result) //->title of the other
} else {
    print("no result")
}
```

(I assume "take first when duplicate" strategy.)

But I strongly doubt if this data structure really fit for your purpose.

Comment: instead of `NSDictionary` , you can use `[[String:String]]` for pure swift :)

Answer (score 0):

At first, dictionary is not an array ....

```
import Foundation
// it is better to use native swift dictionary, i use NSDictionary as you request
var d: NSDictionary = ["111":"title of the video","123":"title of the other","133":"title of  another"]
if let value = d["123"] {
    print("value for key: 123 is", value)
} else {
    print("there is no value with key 123 in my dictionary")
}
// in case, you have an array of dictionaries
let arr = [["111":"title of the video"],["123":"title of the other"],["133":"title of  another"]]
let values = arr.flatMap { (d) -> String? in
    if let v = d["123"] {
        return v
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
print(values) // ["title of the other"]
```