# How to find a value in array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have array of dictionaries:

```
let someArray = [["Andrew":"qwerty"],["Paul":"123456"],["Sarah":"123123"]]
```

And I have a value which I want to find in array

```
let search = "Sarah"
```

I want to know if value "Sarah" exists in the array.How can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Array of Dictionaries for Value in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203443/search-array-of-dictionaries-for-value-in-swift)

Comment: You can use `first(where:{})`, notice that you look for keys and not values, and did you try anything, like a basic for loop?

Comment: @DionizB Don't be so dry with newcomers

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed. Please show that you've tried to solve this in some way by presenting some code. My experience has been that explaining what one has tried often leads to a solution.

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet well before asking a question here in stack overflow, it suggests searching and then if you don't find anything then you can ask your own question

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of dictionaries.

You just need to search the dictionary having a `key == "Sarah"` so

```
let elms = [["Andrew":"qwerty"],["Paul":"123456"],["Sarah":"123123"]]

let sarahDict = elms.first { $0.keys.contains("Sarah") }
```

### Model Value

However a Model Value would make the code much more clear

```
let elms = [["Andrew":"qwerty"],["Paul":"123456"],["Sarah":"123123"]]

struct Person {

    let name: String
    let value: String

    init?(dict:[String:String]) {
        guard let name = dict.keys.first, let value = dict[name] else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}

let person = elms.compactMap(Person.init).first { $0.name == "Sarah" }
```